# Job Error in tOracleOutput and tOracleBulkExec Talend

Tags: oracle, etl, talend

I have difficulty in configuration setting of Component "tOracleOutput" & "tOracleBulkExec" My database is Oracle 32bit. Irrespective of Source i'm unable to set the property type or 'use an existing connection' 
Also I always have some issues with Oracle based components(so i had to opt for tjdbcinput/tjdbcoutput)
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Following is snapshot of my talend jobs:

[image: screen]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should check if your connection works properly : have you declared and verified your connection in 'Metadata' (in Repository view) ?
- In order to use "use an existing connection", you must declare a connection in the repository, and use a tOracleConnection referencing your connection in the beginning of your job.

Can't see any screenshots by the way.

Comment: yes my connection works fine along with declaration and verification of connection in my repository view. This problem is specific to tOracle based all the components, however i don't face any issues with tJDBC based components. Considering the fact my database is Oracle  Client 32 bit why do i face such issues with tOracle based components only. i have to manually go for built-in option and fill details. Tried with tOracleConnection component still this option is not in my drop down list in Basic setting of tOracleOutput, nor m able to choose Property type as repository (follow up snapshot)

Comment: Are you sure the db connection has the right db type selected? And the correct version? Here it works without a problem.

Comment: yes. all those details are filled up correctly.Now its working fine. Thank You :-)